# MultiCheckbox Field Validation with Flask WTForms

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms

I have a WTForm and I am trying to validate a custom multi-checkbox field,

```py
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(html_tag='ol', prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()

class MultiCheckboxAtLeastOne():
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        if not message:
            message = 'At least one option must be selected.'
        self.message = message
        self.field_flags = {"required": True} # Requires each checkbox to be true, even though that's not what __call__ checks for

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if not field.data:
            raise StopValidation(self.message)

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    language = MultiCheckboxField('Language', choices=get_languages(), validators=[MultiCheckboxAtLeastOne()])
```

When I set the `required` flag to true, every checkbox needs to be checked. I just need at least one checkbox to be selected.

When I don't set the `required` flag, the native, and very elusive (is doesn't appear in js, html, or css via developer tools), validation modal doesn't appear, and 'manually' displaying errors is required with,

```
{% for error in form.language.errors %}
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I validate this field properly? I.e. just check if at least one box is true, if not, show the native modal. I also receive `'1', '2', '3', '5', '4' are not valid choices for this field.` if I check all the boxes and submit the form. Why is that?

This is the "native modal" I mention.

[image: The native modal I mention]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control the native validation modal/popup using WTForms. You'll have to use JavaScript, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#implementing_a_customized_error_message).

Should you want to avoid using JS, validation of the multiple select checkbox list with WTForms can be done using

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.fields import SelectMultipleField
from wtforms.validators import StopValidation
from wtforms import widgets

def get_languages():
    return [(1, 'English'), (2, 'French'), (3, 'Spanish'), (4, 'Mandarin'), (5, 'German'), (6, 'Other')]

class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(html_tag='ol', prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()

class MultiCheckboxAtLeastOne():
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        if not message:
            message = 'At least one option must be selected.'
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if len(field.data) == 0:
            raise StopValidation(self.message)

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    language = MultiCheckboxField('Language', choices=get_languages(), validators=[MultiCheckboxAtLeastOne()], coerce=int)
```

Notice the `coerce=int`. This will cast the numeric strings into integers making the field's data compatible with `get_languages()`.

Remove the native validation by adding the attribute `novalidate` to your html  element.

You can skip writing the error conditions for each field by looping through the form fields,

```
<form method="POST" action="/post" novalidate>
  {% for field_name, value in form.data.items() %}
    {% if field_name != 'csrf_token' %}
        {{ form[field_name].label }}

        {% for error in form[field_name].errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}

        {{ form[field_name](size=40) }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {{ form.csrf_token }}

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```